# Unable to insert data into a fusion table I own

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I'm using the fusion table SQL API (1.0) to insert data into a table. I own the table and the table is private. However, when I use the `INSERT INTO` SQL API to insert data into my table I get the error that I don't have permission to execute this method. Since I own the table I don't understand why I don't have the permission to insert.

I used the API explorer to test it. Here is the generated URL:

[https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/fusiontables/v1/fusiontables.query.sql?sql=INSERT+INTO+1kYltHIvQBnfHeAFLwzoSO_F_xTA-Ef6N4MbHmvM+(Name%252C+Location)+VALUES+('Test'%252C+'Address')&_h=2&](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/fusiontables/v1/fusiontables.query.sql?sql=INSERT+INTO+1kYltHIvQBnfHeAFLwzoSO_F_xTA-Ef6N4MbHmvM+%28Name%252C+Location%29+VALUES+%28%27Test%27%252C+%27Address%27%29&_h=2&)

Thanks,
GA

Answer (score 1):

Have you authorized your request with OAuth?  The request needs to have an authorization token that identifies you as the one making the request.

If you are using the API explorer, you can click on the button next to "Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0:" and it will set up the tokens for you automatically.

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using#auth

Comment: yes, i authorized using oauth. i can use the SELECT sql api perfectly. however, i can't seem to modify the fusion table. any ideas?

Comment: How are you doing the authorization? If the table is public `SELECT` works without authorization.

Comment: In the api explorer i just use the "Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0" button. However, I also tried authorizing via the URL using https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?key=<my_api_key>&access_token=<access_token_from_refresh_token>. My table is private and the SELECT works fine with this authorization but INSERT doesn't.